# MY SQL WHERE multiple strings are in a column

Tags: sql, mysql

I am new to SQL statements and need some help. I have two columns, firstname and lastname. I'm trying to clean up the data and extract everything where those two columns do not contain the following strings

- test
- Guest
- .

This is where I am so far.

```
SELECT
  firstname,
  lastname

FROM user
WHERE 
    'test' NOT IN (firstname, lastname) AND
    'Guest' NOT IN (firstname, lastname) AND
    '.' NOT IN (firstname, lastname);
```

I know this is looking at whole words, so I need to be able to find these strings.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `'test'`, `'Guest'`, `'.'` are complete values of `firstname`/`lastname`, or these are substrings within the columns values?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: Yes to both. And in upper and lower case. This data is a mess

Answer (score 3):

I would reverse the conditions and check for the values in each column.

UPDATE: I just read in the comments, that you have to deal with lower- and uppercase as well. I updated the query so that you will find all matches regardless of cases.

```
SELECT
  firstname,
  lastname
FROM user
WHERE LCASE(firstname) NOT IN ('test', 'guest', '.')
  AND LCASE(lastname) NOT IN ('test', 'guest', '.')
```

Comment: Cheers, this pointed me in the right direction, i hope. My query is working, and I've expanded on it. It may not be pretty, but for now it's ok.